# How does regex 0.12 work? IBM Watson transf. Regex \d+\.\d+\.\d+[PZ]\d+ -- into--> Regex 0.12

Tags: regex, xslt

Does someone has some experiences with Regex 0.12 ?

At this moment, we're using Watson Explorer enterprise.
And therefore we've to construct an XSL script which can retrieve perticual meta-data back:

The pattern which we basically need are **3.2.14P5879** or **14.1.1Z5526**

Thus: Digits Dot Digits Dot Digits Letter-P_or_Z Digits

for example, if I've the text:

There was an issue with project **3.2.14P5879**, regarding to document **14.1.1Z5526**-ABC.docx it says that we've to use the documents of "**14.1.1P5526** - xyz.pdf"

Then it would be amazing if we could have the next result:

```
 - <content name="test">3.2.14P5879</content> 
 - <content name="test">14.1.1Z5526</content>
 - <content name="test">14.1.1P5526</content>
```

---

**But now,** 
When we tried to use the next reg-expression

```
 \d+\.\d+\.\d+[PZ]\d+
```

We noticed that it didn't work, and the reason for that is : We think that Watson still uses **regex 0.12**

according to this link : https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS8NLW_11.0.2/com.ibm.swg.im.infosphere.dataexpl.engine.man.doc/r_viv_match.html

and (see the regex specification for detailed information) :

http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/regex/regex_toc.html

**Thus the question is :**

How do you write **\d+.\d+.\d+[PZ]\d+** into a regex 0.12 compatible version?

Plus

How and where can I test such things?
(I don't want to relay on stackoverflow, for each new query)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
[:digit:]+\.[:digit:]+\.[:digit:]+[PF][:digit:]+
```

if I recall correctly.

Comment: Is it okey if I test it next Wednesday? then i've access again to WEX

Comment: @Dieter test it whenever you want !

Comment: Hey, if you edit your code, according to my solution, i'll accept yours as correct - Because you made a little fault

Answer (score 0):

```
[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+[PZ][0-9]+
```

The above reg-expression, will find patterns similar as 123.12.12P1234

If we decompose this expression then we will have 7 sections.

Thus:

**Find me the pattern in the text which contains:**

```
[0-9]+             <-- numbers from 0 to 9 and may repeat e.g. 1 or 02736 
\.                 <-- followed by a single dot "."
[0-9]+             <-- followed by repeatable numbers
\.                 <-- followed by a single dot "."
[0-9]+             <-- followed by repeatable numbers
[PZ]               <-- followed by a single P or Z, but not both
[0-9]+             <-- and ends by repeatable numbers
```

[ A plus sing (+) means, that the values between brackets are repeatable. ]

Some patterns :

- 1.1.1P1
- 1.1.1Z1
- 100.100.100P100
- 1.100.1P1

etc

Comment: @TobySpeight - pleased?